# Best way to sort two arrays in correspondence in a manner that coordination between them does not change

Tags: sorting, c++

Let me put it this way. I have two arrays A and B. Array A contains manufacturing dates of cars, and Array B contains corresponding car model names. A and B are in correspondence. Now I want to sort array A but at the same time the coordination of both arrays should not break. Whats the best way to do that?

Example:
Array A : 1950 1990 1975 1960
Array B : AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD

after sorting,
Array A : 1950 1960 1975 1990
Array B : AAAA DDDD CCCC BBBB

Comment: "zip" the two arrays into one, then sort by the key stored in $A$, and then break this combined array into the sorted $A$ and the corresponding $B$.

Comment: That's useful. thanks